# Find the compatible socket

Tags: java, sockets

I have an ArrayList of sockets. how can I remove from the list the same socket i have in a variable. for example:

```
sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();
sockets.add(socket);
sockets.add(socket1);
sockets.add(socket2);
```

Now i want remove socket1 which it`s index, unknown.

Comment: So you have a bunch of Sockets in an ArrayList, and you have a `Socket` variable, you don't know which one it is, but you want to remove it?

Comment: @rgettman yes. that what i want to do

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have a reference to the `Socket` object that you want to remove, then just call `remove` on your [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
sockets.remove(socket1);
```

This works, because even though [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) doesn't implement the `equals` method, the Object class's reference equality is used.  As long as that `Socket` object is in the `ArrayList`, `remove` will remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveSocketFromAList {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
      List< Socket > sockets = new ArrayList<>( 3 );
      Socket google = new Socket( "www.google.com", 80 );
      Socket bing   = new Socket( "www.bing.com"  , 80 );
      Socket yahoo  = new Socket( "www.yahoo.com" , 80 );
      sockets.add( google );
      sockets.add( bing   );
      sockets.add( yahoo  );
      System.out.println( sockets.size());
      sockets.remove( bing );
      System.out.println( sockets.size());
      System.out.println( sockets );
   }
}
```

Outputs:

```
3
2
[Socket[addr=www.google.com/74.125.230.243,port=80,localport=62411], Socket[addr=www.yahoo.com/87.248.122.122,port=80,localport=62413]]
```

`List.remove()` is effective.

Answer (score -1):

Though you don't provide your code completely but here i give you an example how to remove an item from the arraylist below..

```
// create an empty array list with an initial capacity
    ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(5);

    // use add() method to add values in the list
    arrlist.add("A");
    arrlist.add("B");
    arrlist.add("C");
    arrlist.add("D");
    arrlist.add("E");

    System.out.println("Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

    // let us print all the values available in list
    for (String value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    }  

    // Removes first occurrence of "C"
    arrlist.remove("C");

    System.out.println("Now, Size of list: " + arrlist.size());

    // let us print all the values available in list
    for (String value : arrlist) {
      System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    }
```

**//Another example**

```
ArrayList<String> arlist=new ArrayList<String>();

//<E> it is return type of ArrayList

arlist.add("First Element"); // adding element in ArrayList
arlist.add("Second Element");
arlist.add("Third Element");
arlist.add("forth Element");
arlist.add("fifth Element");

// remove array list element by index number
arlist.remove(3);

// remove ArrayList element by Object value
arlist.remove("fifth Element");

// get elements of ArrayList 
for(int i=0;i<arlist.size();i++)
{
    System.out.println("ArrayList Element "+i+" :"+arlist.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I know i can do it with remove, but when i use sockets, it doesnt work

Comment: sockets.remove() will work as sockets are objects,do you try that?

Comment: @Shelef Doesn't work how? Returns null? Removes the wrong socket?

Comment: @ridoy Two examples of `ArrayList<String>` don't demonstrate how to remove from an `ArrayList<Socket>.`